# CKEditor fieldtype overlaying redactor

Tags: plugin-development, redactor, custom-fieldtype

I've created a Fieldtype to use CK Editor so can take advantage of the advanced table formatting options over Redactor. However I want to keep Redactor for other content management. I came across this post so thought would give it a go: [Craft WYSIWYG editor and CKEditor](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10752/craft-wysiwyg-editor-and-ckeditor)

All seemed to be working well but now whenever I focus on a redactor field the CKEditor buttons pop up. Any thoughts as to why this might be happening? Screenshot:

[image: CKEditor overlaying Redactor]

Fieldtype code posted up at https://gist.github.com/cole007/1ffa5036f8b79516ca34406d7b6833bf

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this?

Cheers

Cole

Comment: Full plugin code at http://cl.ly/0V1F410N1B1s - not written a fieldtype before so apologies if some fundamental mistakes being made in the code!

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it looks like a little conflict around absolute positioning

I've had good success in 'massaging' the Craft CP using: [Craft CPCSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss)

See here for a little more, too: [Remove outdent & indent from Redactor2 "lists" button](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12788/remove-outdent-indent-from-redactor2-lists-button/14786#14786)

Hope it helps, Cole